# how to check li click events to code behind using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have list li,I want to know which option in clicked to code behind.How can i possible

```
<ul class="mega-select__sort">
 <li class="filter-wrap"><a href="#" id="loc" class="mega-select__filter filter--active" runat="server" data-filter='location'>Location</a></li>
 <li class="filter-wrap"><a href="#" id="cine" class="mega-select__filter" runat="server" data-filter='cinema'>Cinema</a></li>
</ul>
```

there are two options one is location and another one is cinema.I want to know which option was clicked to code behind..

Comment: Unordered list is a html control which doesn't raise any event. You can wrap  a link button or something in between the `li` tags and then identify the clicked value.

Comment: Use `LinkButton` or `BulletedList` instead of `hyperlinks`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i know that the user click which <li> option from code behind in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916824/how-can-i-know-that-the-user-click-which-li-option-from-code-behind-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. After a page has finished processing and has been sent to a browser as the HTTP response, server can do nothing with this page.

You need to use POST form to inform the server about your choice. Or you can use JavaScript and AJAX, if you want it to be done without form submitting and reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Use repeater control or Datalist control to list the `<li>` tag. Inside `<li>` take linkbutton. then use itemcommand method to handle it