# How can i know that the user click which <li> option from code behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have two `<li>` items inside `<ul>`.

```
<ul runat="server">
  <li runat="server">Name</li>
  <li runat="server">Genre</li>
</ul>
```

How can i know which option the user was clicked from server,if user clicked Name,i need to know the clicked item is name.Is there is any way to check using aspx with?

Comment: Hi. You have posted [exactly same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893066/how-to-check-li-click-events-to-code-behind-using-asp-net) yesterday. Instead of reposting it every day, please consider some more effort in order to improve the original question, so that it receives better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul id='myList'>
  <li id='1'>First</li>
  <li id='2'>Second</li>
  <li id='3'>Third</li>
  <li id='4'>Fourth</li>
  <li id='5'>Fifth</li>
</ul>

$("#myList li").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // jQuery's .attr() method, same but more verbose
    alert($(this).html()); // gets innerHTML of clicked li
    alert($(this).text()); // gets text contents of clicked li
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i dont know if fetching the value in asp.net is a good idea or not,
you can try javascript for this. 
give this `ul` an `id` or `class`

```
<ul runat="server" class="thisvalue">
```

and check the value inside a javascript function

```
   $(".thisvalue").change(function()

{
    var option = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    if (option = 'name')
    {
          //yourcode
    }
    else if(option = 'Genre')
    {
      // yourcode
    }

}
```